# Access user outside of controller - PassportJS - ExpressJS - MongooseJS

Tags: node.js, mongoose, passport.js

I have an expressjs app, using passportjs as my auth middleware and mongoose to connect to mongdb.

Now my authentification works properly, I can log users. However I need to access the logged in user outside of a route.

On actions such as CRUD operation, I want to log that user X has done Y action. For that I use mongoose hooks to log these actions like so:

```
MySchema.post('findOneAndUpdate', function(doc){
 User.findOne({_id: ???}, function(err, user){
  Log.create({user: user._id, action: 'Updated Document ' + doc._id});
 });
});
```

So right now I'm wondering how to access the currently logged in user from that hook.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Where do you do that code? You need to be in a middleware and/or a route to access the `request` object where you can find the `request.user` object

Comment: that code is un my Schema description file, outside of any request. Why can't I access the user outside of requests? Is all my code supposed to be in requests, I don't think so. If not going through Passport, is there a way to set a global on my app so I can access the current user anywhere? thanks

Comment: Your logic is wrong, if you need to check a user request, you need to have the request. Please add more relevant code because we can't understand what you are doing with that code.

Comment: Hey @Michelem, that code uses Mongoose 'post' hook, which is activated after the 'findOneAndUpdate' action has been performed. In there I need to access the object of the user who is doing that action in order to log what is going on. I think it's a valid use case. For logging purposes I'd rather not add the Log.create() code each time I do a 'findOneAndUpdate' action, therefore I use the hook.